# Sync all Active Directory properties to SP Online User Profiles

Tags: user-profile-property, active-directory-import

I have a need to sync all the properties present in Active Directory to SP Online User Profiles. Can anyone provide the steps to do so?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on which properties are you interested in?

Comment: We have properties like mail, contactNumber, TeamNumber, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online user profile syncs properties from Azure AD. There are fixed set of properties that it syncs which cannot be changed. [See this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3168272/information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-sharepoint-online) for list of properties that SharePoint online syncs from Azure AD. If you would like to sync additional properties you will have to sync manually using a custom application. There is a [user profile bulk import API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online) that you can use to import required properties in a scheduled fashion.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. I hope, this should help me sync all my properties.

Comment: If I have answered your question, please mark it as answer.